# build GCC8.2.0 fails with "checking assembler for -mnan support... no"

Tags: gcc, mips, cross-compiling

I am trying to build cross GCC, version 8.2.0, for Mips target (not mipsel), on host Debian-SID, with mostly latest tools in it, such as gcc x86_64 8.2.0 and make 4.2.1 .

loaded and unpacked these packages and versions (are they listed?):

```
gcc-8.2.0
binutils-2.32
cloog-0.18.4
glibc-2.29
gmp-6.1.2
isl-0.20
mpc-1.1.0
mpfr-4.0.2
```

according to the GCC build documentation, linked them under gcc-8.2.0:

```
cd -- "${SRCDIR}"
ln -s ../mpfr-4.0.2 mpfr
ln -s ../gmp-6.1.2 gmp
ln -s ../mpc-1.1.0 mpc
#ln -s ../isl-0.20 isl
ln -s ../cloog-0.18.4 cloog
ln -s ../binutils-2.32 binutils
```

(since isl lib fails to build and is not needed, I left it out)

then made folder build_gcc (outside sources) and configured.

```
cd ../build_gcc

../gcc-8.2.0/configure --prefix=/home/achim/instgcc --target=mips-linux-gnueabi --enable-languages=c,c++
```

After that passes, start 'make'.

After some time, it exits with:

```
[...]
checking assembler for .micromips support... no
checking assembler for .dtprelword support... no
checking assembler for DSPR1 mult with four accumulators support... no
checking assembler and linker for explicit JALR relocation... no
checking linker for .eh_frame personality relaxation... no
checking assembler for -mnan= support... no
*** This configuration requires the GNU assembler
```

When I build the binutils beforehand, and install them in my /home/achim/gccinst , and add that to path, it does not change it.

When I link the binutils under the gcc-source, no change.

when I install the package "binutils-mips-linux-gnu" from the apt repository, no change. Still complains.

But, doing

```
mips-linux-gnu-as -mnan=2008
mips-linux-gnu-as -mnan=legacy
```

on the shell, the assembler is there and recognizes the -mnan Option.

Any idea?

What did I miss in the documentation? Most hints on webpages of how to build crosscompilers are old and refer to versions of GCC such as 4.9 .

Or is Mips target slowly dying?

The Debian-SID ist mostly fresh installed, to try to get this build through.